# Tabs or toggle to switch between contact forms?

Tags: tabs, toggle, contact-us, wordpress

I have a 1-pager with the primary objective being to have the (somewhat-qualified) user initiate contact of some sort. IT is for a SUPER, super small business, so a direct phone call would be both handleable and probably preferable, BUT of course we need to have a contact form on the page. To take it up a notch, I decided to add in the ability to schedule a free consult right from the page, should the user be ready for that.

Ideally, I think I'd have 2 steps:

1. give your name, phone, address, etc
2. request a date and time (if
   they care to schedule an appointment as opposed to just sending a
   message)

Unfortunately, the client seems to be heavily invested in the WP plugin I'm currently using that serves as a whole client portal as well as a means of contact info collection and appointment scheduling. And as such, the process cannot be broken up like this. They are 2 separate widgets that collect the contact data in different places/times. To accommodate,

What I feel I'm left with is either the route of:

- having the "Get Started" section consisist of 
  2 tabs, "Send Message", where a basic contact form would be presented and its data emailed to the appropriate user and "Schedule Appointment", where the calendar/time-slot UI would be presented with Step 2 of that being collecting the contact info.

**OR**

- having the "Get Started" section show both the basic contact form and the calendar side by side with 1 or the other of them being disabled while the other is active. A toggle switch above the 2 widgets would determine which was active.

Both options (not yet styled to match the rest of the page) can be viewed at http://uat1.one-pager.sugarloafculinary.com/#section-contact and http://uat1.one-pager.sugarloafculinary.com/#section-contact2 respectively.

I"m inclined to deduce that the 2nd option (toggle switch) may be too complicated for many reasons. I DO think providing a means of setting an appointment directly through the web site will be appealing and thus showing a (greyed out... aka disabled) calendar right next to the contact form (as in option 2) could prove to be more tempting and readily apparent than having it hidden until its tab is clicked (as in option 1), but I'm going back and forth on how much value that adds vs the potential pitfall of hoping the user understands both what exactly a toggle switch is and how to work it.

Thanks for advance for any wisdom you may have to share.

-daveh0

Comment: Couldn't view either of your links...

Comment: I could only find the tabbed view. I didn't see any toggle version in your links. You could also remove quite a bit of text from your question to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that, ideally, it would be best to combine the two in a single form. However, given the contraints that you mention, I'd go with your first proposal of having two tabs. It is more intutive compared to the toggle alternative and gives the user a simple binary choice between two self-explanatory choices. I'd have the consult tab as the default to avoid people using the message tab to request a consult.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I cannot see the toggle version (they both look the same)

I think you are adding a lot of content on an already busy page.

By presenting two options (with *a lot* of copy on each side) you're creating cognitive overload and choice paralysis.

Taking that into consideration, I personally do not think that having tabs OR a toggle is the right idea since you're just adding extra controls and copy.

Would you consider having a simple section titled "Contact us" and either:

**A.** Have just two buttons one saying "Send us a message" and one "Book a consultation" with a line of copy underneath each. Then you either take them on a separate page or show content underneath in a timely manner.

or

**B.** Make a decision on which one is a priority. If consultations are a priority then have that form front and center on its own with simple copy with a button somewhere "Or send us a message" that will take users to a normal contact form

Both of the above are measurable via analytics, easy to test and slightly more future proof especially if they lead to their own funnel path. So if you ever need to make changes to one (e.g the calendar form) you don't have to worry about breaking something in the other.

Now, I hope you are ok with me providing some unsolicited advice:

1. There's a lot of stuff flying in as I scroll and load the site. It can be quite overwhelming.
2. Body text is too thin to read even on a retina macbook.
3. I counted at least 4 different fonts on that page. Lacks consistency.
4. Generally there's **a lot** of copy, even on and around the contact form. Again, very overwhelming and the weird thing is that I still don't know what the company really does.
5. The font at the header is so "quirky" it almost makes the e-mail address and phone number illegible.
6. Lastly, even when I scroll to the contact section I still need to click on the first tab to see its content, it doesn't load automatically

I would personally limit the overall copy of the page, make it punchier, bigger and more legible and then I would bring the form/calendar closer to the top.

Comment: thanks for the thoughtful answer as well as the 'unsolicited advice'. A few thoughts/questions in response: yes I had to ditch the toggle switch... it was confusing people in our, admittedly limited, test sample. Also i think you're right in the fact that the 'get started section' should probably link to a separate page - unfortunately at the moment, without creating extra pages choc full of fluff, the client doesn't have much msgsng nailed down to say anything about their services that can't be said on that one home page. I don't think creating additional clicks for the same content is good.

Comment: continued from previous... can you elaborate on how you might make it more clear what the company does? Both the the hero image as well as the the headline of the 'About Us' section use the phrase 'Personal chef'... reading on, if that phrase were of interest to a user, more detail about how these services would be of use to said user is in the probably-too-wordy body copy. I'm not being defensive -  I def value your input and just want to understand better. PS - production version is at www.sugarloafculinary.com. All in all, perhaps more pages with better/focused content is the next step?